# PHP: Captain Oh Captain, My Switch Case Sucks

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm trying to build a simple switch case demo here and I had it working on my school server and am now trying to carry it over to my server now that the quarter is over. I don't know what happened, the switch case  was working but no longer is and I am trying to repair it. Paths are good, and i've gone through the file forwards and backwards trying to find the error in my logic, looked for missing semicolons, and everything else that i can think to do. I'm stumped and not sure what the issue is but it seems my switch case isn't delivering anything and is somehow broken.

The switch case, when working, would ideally display the date, a poster graphic and unique background image to the client (Browser).

jpg of how page would display: http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc240/_img/img_240a010sm.jpg
Link to page: http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc240/itc240_a020/index.php

```
<?php
/*
 *  a3_Dates-Conditionals.php
 *
 *  Create a page with the following functionality:
 *  Use PHP to deliver a different image and bit of content
 *  for each weekday (Sunday to Saturday) using one PHP file.
 *
 *  STAGE1 - Build it static (check)
 *  STAGE2 - build with variables (test, check)
 *  STAGE3 - Build with conditionals
 */

//http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
$today = date("D, M j");

$test = ' ';
//http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
$strSun = ' ';
$strMon = ' ';
$strTues = ' ';
$strWeds = ' ';
$strThurs = ' ';
$strFri = ' ';
$strSat = ' ';

$linkSun = 'bg_img01.jpg';
$linkMon = 'bg_img02.jpg';
$linkTues = 'bg_img03.jpg';
$linkWeds = 'bg_img04.jpg';
$linkThurs = 'bg_img05.jpg';
$linkFri = 'bg_img06.jpg';
$linkSat = 'bg_img07.jpg';

$linkPoster = ' ';//isn't setting

switch (intval(date("N"))) {
case 0:
    $strSun = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Sunday'; //isn't setting
    $linkSun = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-01.jpg';
    break;
case 1:
    $strMon = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Monday';
    $linkMon = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-02.jpg';
    break;
case 2:
    $strTues = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Tuesday';
    $linkTues = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-03.jpg';
    break;
case 3:
    $strWeds = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'New Comic book Day!';
    $linkWeds = "bg_imgComicBooks.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-04.jpg';
    break;
case 4:
    $strThurs = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Thursday';
    $linkThurs = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-05.jpg';
    break;
case 5:
    $strFri = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Friday';
    $linkFri = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-06.jpg';
    break;
case 6:
    $strSat = 'class="current"';
    $todayIs = 'Saturday';
    $linkSat = "bg_imgSpecial.jpg";
    $linkPoster = 'img_poster-07.jpg';
    break;
}

?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head> <title>a3 | itc240 (w14)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ubuntu_400.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ubuntu_700.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bgSlider.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bg.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <div style='clear:both;text-align:center;position:relative'>
            <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
 <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body id="page1">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <div id="bgSlider"></div>
    <div class="extra">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="box">
 <!-- header --> <header> <h1><a href="index.html"     id="logo">Max |        <sup>itc</sup>240</a></h1>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li> <br > <img src="images/<?=$linkPoster;?>" alt=""> </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><strong><?=$today;?></strong></a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
<!--content -->
                <article id="content">
                    <div class="ic"><!--Content Here... --</div>
                </article id="content">

<!-- / content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg1">
        <div class="main">
<!-- footer -->
            <footer>
                <div class="bg_spinner"></div>

                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li <?=$strSun;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkSun;?>">S</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strMon;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkMon;?>">M</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strTues;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkTues;?>">T</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strWeds;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkWeds;?>">W</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strThurs;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkThurs;?>">Th</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strFri;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkFri;?>">F</a></li>
                    <li <?=$strSat;?> ><a href="images/<?=$linkSat;?>">S</a></li>
                </ul>


                <div class="col_1">
                    <a href="index.html" id="footer_logo">ZZZ</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col_2">
                     <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.max-o-matic.com/" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
                    <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                </div>
            </footer>
<!-- / footer-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.spinner').fadeOut();
        $('body').css({overflow:'inherit'})
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code on my own server,

First of all, date("N") returns 1-7, and not 0 to 6, so you'll be missing one.
As a habit, always add default: to a case switch, so you can catch unexpected results.

Try using date("w") instead.  (lowercase w)

Other than that, Your code is fine

Comment: Thank you - I will go explore this. I thought things always worked from '0' to X, i didn't realize that this worked from '1' to x. Thank you for the guidance i will explore.

Comment: Always consult the PHP docs when in doubt, It solves alot of "getting started with php" questions, their docs are pretty good.

Comment: I did consult it, but there is so much there and it can be overwhelming at times and trying to remember that A is 'A' unless it's 'B' as in this case i thought i was returning an int to the switch case and I thought that it started at zero. My mistake - learned a bit here and i'm thankful for he help

Comment: No worries :) Gotta start somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) the PHP `date` function `N` format specifier returns a value in the range 1-7. Your switch statement is expecting 0-6. Today is Sunday, so the `date` call is returning 7 and your switch statement isn't handling that.